# What is the best method of storing user journal entries in an Android application?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development so bear with me. In part of the app I am developing, the user should be able to enter notes, stories, journal entries, etc. and view old ones (purely in text form at this point). To do this I need a way to save and access these user provided entries.

What is the best way to do this? (in general terms, I don't need specific code although it would be awesome as an example) Do I use a database? The device's internal storage? Remember, the user must be able to view these at leisure, but doesn't necessarily need to be able to share them with others.

If you could link to a tutorial for the appropriate method of storage then I would be very grateful

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) it should give you all the information you will need to store information in applications.  Read through this and determine what will be best depending on your goals and needs of your application.

Answer (score 0):

For your app it would be best to use the DB. You can refer to the [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) for sample code.

The user will not have direct access to it , your app will be used to show the entries.